# Appropriate location to store Themes/Skins

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'm writing a Windows Forms application that is 100% skin-able. I have a Themes folder which contains Skins. Each skin goes inside that folder and I don't want to put that folder in the user's Documents folder and I don't want it to have a user-defined location either.

I want to put it in my application's `App_Data` path. Is this an appropriate place to store Skins/Themes for my application?

`Users/Aeron/App_Data/Local/MyApplication/Themes/CustomSkin1/`

Comment: Are they user modifiable? Are they shared across versions? If answer is "no" for both of them then you _may_ store them in application installation folder. You'll keep your app xcopy deployable. If they don't need to be changed/customized then they're "normal" support files (eligible to stay together with executables).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Yes, the user will be able to create their own skins and even modify the original. I have created a Skin Builder for this. I'd rather not put it in the Program Files folder since the app could possibly run into permission issues which I'd rather try to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995853.aspx) you should store **'Per user, non-roaming' settings** in the 'Application Data Folder', namely:

> [user profile]\AppData\Local\

Roaming data should be saved in

> [user profile]\AppData\Roaming\

(converted locations to newer paths)

Comment: In Windows 8 and 8.1 there is no `Local Settings` folder so I'm assuming you mean `App_Data/Local/`?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The skins for this application are modifiable and also contain application-specific settings. Certain settings are tied-in with skins so the user has more room to customize.

Comment: @Aeron yes, I just read your comment. Then yes +1, I agree with Patrick!

Comment: Trying to find newer reference, but can't find them now.

Comment: I can't find them either. I was looking for them before because I vaguely remember reading over them last year. Thanks for your help @PatrickHofman - I will accept this answer once the timer runs out.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes.

In my opinion just save the skins where you can find them on every machine. 
With App_Data you can find them and "hide" them for "casual" user.